# find and replace text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html:

```
<input id="replace"></input>
<div id="replacepls">Go!</div>
<br>
<textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
```

and some js code there:

```
$('textarea[name=text]').val('Hello my dear friend, i love u');

$('#replacepls').click(function(){

    var news = $('#replace').val();    

    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('friend', news)); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j1ksrdcp/

How can i replace word "friend" in textarea to other word from input on button click? Why my code does not work? Thank you.

Comment: `this` refers to the div element, not the textarea element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/j1ksrdcp/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `val()` instead of `text()`, and also i simplified your code

```
$('#replacepls').click(function () {
    $("#text").val(function (i, val) {
        return val.replace('friend', $('#replace').val())
    });

})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1ksrdcp/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to use val() instead of text() with `textarea`, $(this).text() will give you text of `div` with text Go but not the text in the `textarea`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j1ksrdcp/1/)**

```
$('textarea[name=text]').val('Hello my dear friend, i love u');
$('#replacepls').click(function () {
    var news = $('#replace').val();
    var text = $('#text').val();
    $('#text').val(text.replace('friend', news));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(this).text(text.replace('friend', news));`

With:

```
 $(this).text($("#text").val().replace('friend', news));
```